# Non-exhaustive patterns in haskell, created data type

Tags: haskell

I'm getting a Non-exhaustive pattern in my code on the 2nd line here , i think its intrusive as i need it for my recursion to stop at some point.
It says patterns not matched : [ ] _

```
allergyFree :: [Ingredient] -> [Cupcake] -> [Cupcake]
allergyFree (y:ys) [] = []
allergyFree (y:ys) (c:cs) = if(not(igPresent (y:ys) recipeN)) then ([c] ++ (allergyFree (y:ys) cs))
                            else (allergyFree (y:ys) cs)

where
CC (P priceN) recipeN = c
igPresent :: [Ingredient] -> [Ingredient] -> Bool
igPresent [] recipeN = False
igPresent (y:ys) recipeN = if (y `elem` recipeN) then True
                           else igPresent ys recipeN
```

Any help would be appreciated !

P.s. i'm quite new to haskell

Comment: Question: What happens when you call `allergyFree [] _somethingelse`? There’s your non-exhaustive pattern.

Comment: yeah, i would get errors, i realized what was wrong and defined explicitly all the cases of the lists being empty, Thanks!

Comment: I expect this can be written much more concisely; e.g. something like ```allergyFree allergies = filter (\(CC _ recipe) -> all (`notElem` recipe) allergies)```. That way also seems quite readable to me.

Comment: Enable warnings using `-Wall`. If you do, GHC warns you about the cases you failed to handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(y:ys)` only matches non-empty lists - it refers to a list with first element `y` (and `ys` refers to the rest of the list). Since both of your patterns have `(y:ys)` for the first argument, the function will fail with this error if you ever try to pass it an empty list in that position.

I've only glanced at your code briefly, but since you don't use the `y` or `ys` variables individually anywhere in the function definition, this should work if you replace the `(y:ys)` pattern with a single name, say `x`, and then use `x` anywhere you have `(y:ys)` in your current definition.

Comment: Thanks ! rather than doing that i just defined all cases of both the lists being empty; explicitly; as i wanted to use x and xs and didnt want to use the head and tail functions

Answer (score 2):

When you do pattern matching over two list, you must add the patter of the empty list on both cases (if you want your function to be total):

```
allergyFree :: [Ingredient] -> [Cupcake] -> [Cupcake]
allergyFree _ [] = [] -- second list is empty, I don't care about the first
allergyFree [] _ = [] -- first list is empty, I don't care about the second
allergyFree (y:ys) (c:cs) = -- logic when both has elements
```